# How do I create a function to add to existing information?

Tags: php, mysql

I have existing code that has a string of words. I need to be able to create a function that will add to that existing string of words. I am struggling with how to do this in php. I am new to it and all I have looked up previously has gotten me nowhere.

When all is said and done, this is what I would like:

a function to add a new word to an existing variable that contains a string of words. (below is existing code of words)

```
$words = 'Apple Sauce, Tasty Chicken, New Monkey, Left Right';
```

Below is all I can come up with:

```
function newWord($word){
   $newAlpha = 'Time Table';
   if ($newAlpha > 0){
      echo $newAlpha => $words; 
  }
}
```

I know that's not right but I'm very new to php and mysql. It may be worth noting that ultimately I need the function to get inserted into a database where $words are housed, but that would be a bonus if someone could help me with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just concatenate it with the string:

```
function newWord($word, $words){
   if($word != ''){//or any other check you want
       return "$words, $word"; 
   }
   return $words;
}
```

Usage:

```
$newAlpha = 'Time Table';
$words = newWord($newAlpha,$words);//now $words has $newAlpha appended onto the end with comma and space
```

You can see it in action here:

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/436189dc45208fb78bdfa4262772600559f29d44

Comment: I thought about this, yet I wanted something that would input the new word in the function because I need to make it go through some checks before I added it to the existing group of words. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: I green checked it because this is the best answer and I'm using it, but it still doesn't append the words to the existing words. Any idea why? And what I mean by that is, the new word doesn't show up but the code runs.

Comment: How is that possible? Check that demo page I added to the answer. Oh, I see, you expected this function to echo new version of the string? Just change return to echo then, but then you lose the new value of that variable because it exists only in the scope of the function if you don't return it.

Comment: You're right, I'm gonna keep tweaking it for what I need. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the concat operator `.`

```
$words = 'Apple Sauce, Tasty Chicken, New Monkey, Left Right';
$added_words = $words .'new_word_one, new_word_two, etc...';
var_dump($added_words); 
// produces (string)"Apple Sauce, Tasty Chicken, New Monkey, Left Right new_word_one, new_word_two, etc..."
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$words = 'Apple Sauce, Tasty Chicken, New Monkey, Left Right';
$new_plus_old_words = "$words new_word1, new_word2, new_word3";
```